# React Flow how to define interface for a static class method?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I want my class to implement a custom interface IWizard as a static class method:
types.js:

```
//@flow
export interface IWizard {
    getFormName: () => string;
}
```

CustomerWizard.js:

```
...

export class CustomerWizard extends React.PureComponent<Props, State>
    implements IWizard {
    static getFormName(): string {
        return 'customerWizard';
    }

...
```

It doesn't work - flow complains. Are static methods not supported in interfaces?

Comment: Not supported. If it would, you'd need to specify some special keyword (like `static`) to differentiate static method from instance method. Anyway not supported